# avoid overflow from table margin

Tags: html, birt

I've a table that needs to be indented containing an inner table, but because it's using margin, the table overflows the parent container. The DOM looks like below, also please see this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lxjdwce5/:

```
<body>
<div>
<table class="T1">
<tr><td>
<table class="InnerT">
<tr><td>Some contents to be indented</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other contents to be indented</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there a solution only by changing the "leftIndent" style?
Since I'm using BIRT which generates this structure, I'd rather not modify the DOM or move CSS styles to other elements.

Thank you

Comment: Can you [add another table cell](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxjdwce5/3/) and make it 50px wide, then remove the `margin-left` from the T1 class? *If you cannot modify the DOM, what can you change and how can you change it? Is js your only allowable solution, or ?*

Answer (score 0):

BIRT supports Fixed Layout and Auto layout. Change into Auto layout, it will adjust the table for the page automatically.

Go to property editor, you will find the layout options.